# Internationalization in struts

Tags: internationalization

I made one struts application.I want to support a Internationalization in my application for
japanese.My Property file name is Application,Its working for Application_ja.properties file but
Its not working for Application_ja_JP.properties file.I am running a application on tomcat server.
please help me.

Comment: If you want to get some answers, please accept some on previous questions (unless you feel your question has not been answered).

Comment: Care to paste some code fragment on how you read from resources? And how you are creating Locale objects and passing them around? Right now it is actually impossible to answer your question other than "you have a codding error somewhere". I doubt you would like to read such an answer...

Answer (score 0):

I have created application to support two languages. I case you did not paste some code I will try to explain mine.

At first I create Struts action class to handle locales, there are methods of this class:

```
public ActionForward en(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form,
        HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws Exception {      
    request.getSession().setAttribute(
            Globals.LOCALE_KEY, Locale.ENGLISH);
    return mapping.findForward(SUCCESS);
}

public ActionForward lt(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form,
        HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws Exception {

    request.getSession().setAttribute(
            Globals.LOCALE_KEY, new Locale("lt"));

    return mapping.findForward(SUCCESS);
}
```

One method for English and one method for Lithuanian language.

I declared this action class in my struts-config.xml file:

```
<action input="/views/index.jsp" 
        parameter="method" 
        path="/locale" 
        scope="request" 
        type="lt.klc.action.LanguageSelectAction" 
        validate="false">
    <forward name="success" path="/views/index.jsp"/>
</action>
```

I declared my resources: (application.properties and application_lt.properties)

```
<message-resources parameter="lt/klc/resources/application_lt"/>    
<message-resources parameter="lt/klc/resources/application"/>
```

When I want to chage language I simple call this class by providing which method I want to call:

```
    <html:link action="locale.xhtml?method=en">English</html:link>
    <html:link action="locale.xhtml?method=lt">Lietuviškai</html:link>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
Suppose you have two properties files-
struts_en_UK.properties
common.color = colour

struts_en_US.properties
common.color = color

The following code will fetch the resource from properties file as follows-
        Locale locale = new Locale("en", "UK");
        ResourceBundle bundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("struts",locale);

        System.out.println(bundle.getString("common.color"));

        Locale usLocale = new Locale("en", "US");
        ResourceBundle usBundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("struts",usLocale);
        System.out.println("Us Locale : "+usBundle.getString("common.color"));
```